# How can make Firebase Crashlytics stack trace clear in Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Currently I integrate Firebase to use Crashlytics but I got exception's stack trace like this
[image]

Look at the stack trace, I do not know what the issue is. Can you give me some advices or should I use  another Tool for Crashlytics?

Answer (score 0):

As for me, AppCenter is the best too for Xamarin based application. The screenshot below shows example of the error.

[image]